# Compare arrays and compact it if in same order

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

Let's say we have these arrays:

```
$a = array("B", "C", "D", "E");
$b = array("A", "B" , "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I");
```

Then I want to check if a sub sequence from `$a` is consecutive in `$b`. If yes and it is more than 3 elements I want to output them with a dash, e.g. `X-Y`. In all other cases I just want to print out the values comma separated.

So expected output from the above `$a` array would be:

```
B-E
```

Another example:

```
$a = array("B", "C", "D", "F", "H");
//Same $b array to check if a sub sequence of $a appears in $b consecutive
```

Expected output:

```
B-D, F, H
```

I've tried some crazy foreach in a foreach loop that checks values in both arrays and sets pointers and then compares the pointers. That felt way too complicated and now my head hurts.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and this is super simple thing.

**Edit:** Here is my current progress.

```
$pointer = count($b);
$a = array("B", "C" , "D", "E");
$b = array("A", "B", "C" , "D", "E", "F", "G");

foreach ($b as $key => $bb) {
    if ($a[0] == $bb) {
        $pointer = $key;
    }
}


$d = array();
$d[] = $a[0];
foreach ($a as $key => $aa) {
    if ($aa == $b[$pointer+$key]) {
        $pointer = $key;
    } else {
        $d[] = "-".$aa;
        $pointer++;
    }
}
echo implode('',$d);
```

**Edit 2:** The values are not just letters. They are strings and can be of different lengths. ("AA", "b", "lk") for example.

Comment: *I've tried some crazy foreach* Show us that crazy code and we will show you how to get that crazy code to work

Comment: Not clear on what exactly you want, do you want to skip any specific value or few values? be much clear please

Comment: @Rizier123 I added the code I tried to make after I gave up on the loops.

Comment: @M3ghana I thought I was very clear. If the first array has same values in the same order **at some point** in the second array ($a and $b) you only show the first and last values from the array. If the first array skips some values from the second one, it should still show the values the same way, but list the odd ones individually. There's probably a word to describe this but I don't know it.

Comment: Your question is unclear as to how the two arrays fit together. Are you looking to find the *intersection* of the two arrays and then compact it to the meta list using hyphenation to denote a contiguous range of characters?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston They fit together through their values that are strings. "A" is "A" and "B" is "B". I should've added to the question that the values aren't just letters. It was purely for the example.

Comment: @Cheppa it still isn't clear how the second array `$b` fits in. Are you expecting the output to only process the *intersection* of the of the two arrays?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Second array is an array of all the possible values for the first array. That's why the first array can be compared to the second. I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by the intersection. If the values appear in the compared array in the same order, the values in between the found values are not showed and - is put in their place instead. If there are values that are not in the same order they are showed with a comma in between.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question of intersection. Can `$a` have a value that is not present in `$b`? Can `$a` have values that are in a different order than `$b`? For example `a = val1, val3, val2` vs `b = val1, val2, val3`.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Ah, sorry I didn't understand at first. No they are in same order. $a does not have other values than $b. Actually if the order is different it is possible to sort $a with the values of $b assuming they are the same and they are using array_multisort().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through the entire array and in each iteration just print the current value of the iteration.

Then in the while loop check if there is still a next element in the array or not with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) AND if the current array element is equals to the next one.

This can simply be done, by getting the ASCII value of the character with [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) and add one before you compare it.

If they are equal you increment `$i` and `$followUp`.

After the loop you can check if you have more than 1 character which follow's up the current one (.e.g: `A`, `D` = 0 follow Up, `A`, `B`, `D` = 1 follow Up; `A`, `B`, `C` = 2 follow Up). And if you have more than 1 you print this value with a dash in between.

Then if it is not the end of the array also print a comma to separate the values.

At the end of the for loop just check if you only had 1 follow Up and reverse the increment of `$i` + reset `$followUp` by assigning 0.

```
<?php

    $a = array("A", "B", "C", "F", "H", "K", "L", "M", "N", "R", "S", "X", "Y", "Z");

    $length = count($a);
    $followUp = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        echo $a[$i];

        while(isset($a[$i+1]) && (ord($a[$i]) + 1) == ord($a[$i+1])){
            ++$followUp;
            ++$i;
        }

        if($followUp > 1)
            echo "-" . $a[$i];

        if($i != count($a) - 1)
            echo ",";

        if($followUp == 1) --$i;
        $followUp = 0;

    }

?>
```

output:

```
A-C,F,H,K-N,R,S,X-Z
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to check if the sub sequences are in the other array in the same order, you can simply change the while condition a bit.

Just [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the search array and check with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) if the sub Array which you can get with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and also implode into a string, is in the search array.

```
<?php

    $a = array("A", "B", "C", "F", "H", "K", "L", "M", "N", "R", "S", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $b = array("A", "B" , "C", "D", "E","F", "H", "M", "N", "R", "S", "F", "G", "H", "I", "M", "N", "R", "S");

    $length = count($a);
    $followUp = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        echo $a[$i];
        $current = $i;
        while(isset($a[$i]) && strpos(implode("|", $b), implode("|", array_slice($a, $current, $followUp+1))) !== FALSE){
            ++$followUp;
            ++$i;
        }

        if($followUp > 2)
            echo "-" . $a[--$i];

        if($i != count($a) - 1)
            echo ",";

        if($followUp <= 2) $i = $current;
        $followUp = 0;

    }

?>
```

output:

```
A-C,F,H,K,L,M-S,X,Y,Z
```

Comment: Aww, you beat me to using ord.

Comment: and I accidentally did it in JS too, so my answer is useless.

Comment: Awesome answer for my question. Though I should've added that the values in the array can be anything: ("b", "FF", "12", "a"); so it would show "FF-a" for ("FF", "12", "a")

Comment: @Cheppa Why would you put a dash between `FF` and `a` ? How do they "follow" each other?

Comment: @Rizier123 They follow each other in the array. It's in the same order as in the array that it is compared to.

Comment: @Cheppa updated my answer. I think I now know what you want.

Comment: @Rizier123 That is pretty smart. It would've taken a long time for me to think about using implode in strpos. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It has only one loop.

```
$a = array("A", "B", "C", "F", "H", "K", "L", "M", "N", "R", "S", "X", "Y", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD");
$d = [];

$isFollow = false;

foreach($a as $el){
    if (count($d) == 0){
        $d[] = $el;
        continue;
    }

    $next = $d[count($d) - 1];
    $next++;

    if ($el == $next){
        $isFollow ? $d[count($d) - 1] = $el : $d[] = $el;
        $isFollow = true;
    } else {
        if ($isFollow){
            $d[count($d) - 2] .= "-".$d[count($d) - 1];
            $d[count($d) - 1] = $el;
        } else $d []= $el;

        $isFollow = false;
    }
}

if ($isFollow){
    $d[count($d) - 2] .= "-".$d[count($d) - 1];
    unset($d[count($d) - 1]);
}

echo implode(',', $d);
```

Output is

```
A-C, F, H, K-N, R-S, X-Y, AA-AD
```

You can write your method of comparing consecutive elements instead

```
$next = $d[count($d) - 1];
$next++;
if ($el == $next)
```